# Get Max Count SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am missing something simple but I can't quite figure it out.

I need to essentially get the Max Count of a Column.

```
SELECT 
    S.Type AS Type, 
    S.Version, 
    COUNT(R.FK_StoveNbr) AS TimesRepaired

FROM STOVE AS S
FULL JOIN STOVE_REPAIR AS R 
ON S.SerialNumber = R.FK_StoveNbr

GROUP BY S.Type, S.Version
ORDER BY TimesRepaired DESC;
```

This gives me the information I need, but now I need to make it so it only displays the Type with the highest number from the COUNT(R.FK_StoveNbr).

Some information:

```
[STOVE_REPAIR](
[RepairNbr] [int] NOT NULL,
[FK_StoveNbr] [int] NOT NULL,
[RepairDt] [smalldatetime] NOT NULL,
[Description] [varchar](500) NULL,
[Cost] [numeric](7, 2) NULL,
[FK_CustomerID] [int] NOT NULL,
[FK_EmpID] [int] NULL,

[STOVE](
[SerialNumber] [int] NOT NULL,
[Type] [char](15) NOT NULL,
[Version] [char](15) NULL,
[DateOfManufacture] [smalldatetime] NULL,
[Color] [varchar](12) NULL,
[FK_EmpId] [int] NULL,
```

Needed output:

```
 type        version   times repaired
 ---------    -----     --------------
 FiredAlways    2            2
```

The Output I have:

```
 type            version   times repaired
 ---------        -----     --------------
 FiredAlways        2               2
 FiredAlways        1               1
 FiredNow           2               1 
 FiredNow           3               1
 FiredNow           1               1
 FiredAlways        4               0
 FiredAlways        5               0
 FiredAlways        3               0
 FiredAtCamp        3               0
 FiredAtCamp        1               0
 FiredAtCamp        2               0
```

Comment: Can't you just TOP 1 it?

Comment: TOP 1 WITH TIES if you want to return more than 1 row when there is a tie for first place.

Answer (score 2):

Use `TOP 1` or `TOP (1) WITH TIES`.  The latter is used when you have ties and you want all the highest numbers.

However, I question your use of `FULL JOIN`.  Doesn't this do what you want?

```
SELECT TOP (1) S.Type AS Type, S.Version, 
       COUNT(R.FK_StoveNbr) AS TimesRepaired
FROM STOVE S INNER JOIN
     STOVE_REPAIR R 
     ON S.SerialNumber = R.FK_StoveNbr
GROUP BY S.Type, S.Version
ORDER BY TimesRepaired DESC;
```

Because you are getting the highest number, I think we can assume that there is at least one repair record for the stove that is returned.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to select the N records that have the highest count, you can do the following:

```
;WITH CountResults AS
(
    SELECT 
        S.Type AS Type, 
        S.Version, 
        COUNT(R.FK_StoveNbr) AS TimesRepaired
    FROM 
        STOVE AS S
        FULL JOIN STOVE_REPAIR AS R ON S.SerialNumber = R.FK_StoveNbr
    GROUP BY 
        S.Type, 
        S.Version
),
MaxCountResults AS
(
    SELECT
        MaxCountResult = MAX(C.TimesRepaired)
    FROM
        CountResults AS C
)
SELECT
    C.Type,
    C.Version,
    C.TimesRepaired
FROM
    CountResults AS C
    INNER JOIN MaxCountResults AS M ON C.TimesRepaired = M.MaxCountResult
ORDER BY
    C.TimesRepaired DESC
```

Basically you determine the highest number first, then filter the whole results by that number.

If you just need 1 with the highest, a simple `TOP` should suffice:

```
SELECT TOP 1
    S.Type AS Type, 
    S.Version, 
    COUNT(R.FK_StoveNbr) AS TimesRepaired
FROM 
    STOVE AS S
    FULL JOIN STOVE_REPAIR AS R ON S.SerialNumber = R.FK_StoveNbr
GROUP BY 
    S.Type, 
    S.Version
ORDER BY
    TimesRepaired DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

The `MAX` and `COUNT` are two different functions that return two different values.  You say

> I need to essentially get the Max Count of a Column.
>   This gives me the information I need, but now I need to make it so it
>   only displays the Type with the highest number from the
>   COUNT(R.FK_StoveNbr)

When you run the code you referenced...

```
SELECT 
 S.Type AS Type, 
 S.Version, 
 COUNT(R.FK_StoveNbr) AS TimesRepaired

FROM STOVE AS S
FULL JOIN STOVE_REPAIR AS R 
ON S.SerialNumber = R.FK_StoveNbr

GROUP BY S.Type, S.Version
ORDER BY TimesRepaired DESC;
```

You get a table that has the "TYPE", "VERSION" and "COUNT" - which represents the number of times that type and version appear in the data set.
You say that you need just the 1 record...

```
type        version   times repaired
 ---------    -----     --------------
 FiredAlways    2            2
```

Would there be a need for other "MAX" of other types?  Such as...

```
type        version   times repaired
---------    -----     --------------
FiredAlways    2            2
FiredAtCamp        3               0
FiredNow           2               1
```

There is always a few ways to do things, depending on how things are setup and what you are truly looking for.  Which is why I restate things above and ask those questions, just for clarity.
In order to get something like what I had posted, what I would recommend doing is a JOIN to a SUBQUERY.  Where the subquery is looking for the MAX of the COUNT based on the TYPE.  Then this subquery is joined back to the original result set using the TYPE and the COUNT.
Off the top of my head it could be such as....

```
SELECT 
 S.Type AS Type, 
 S.Version, 
 COUNT(R.FK_StoveNbr) AS TimesRepaired

FROM STOVE AS S
FULL JOIN STOVE_REPAIR AS R 
  ON S.SerialNumber = R.FK_StoveNbr
INNER JOIN ( SELECT 
               S2.Type AS Type,  
               MAX(COUNT(R2.FK_StoveNbr)) AS MXTimesRepaired
             FROM STOVE AS S2
             FULL JOIN STOVE_REPAIR AS R2
               ON S2.SerialNumber = R2.FK_StoveNbr
           ) AS SI
ON S.Type = SI.Type

GROUP BY S.Type, S.Version
HAVING COUNT(R.FK_StoveNbr) = SI.MXTimesRepaired
ORDER BY TimesRepaired DESC;
```

I know that would give you a slightly smaller result set that has a distinct set that would still have multiple records based on the type.
However, without knowing more about some of the other fields, the question needs to be "what makes that record you are looking for the MAX or only record needed?"  Is there a ID field that we can look at or something else that would make us want to look for that one record?